# How can URL Rewrite match http headers with underscores?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

How can URL rewrite match a request where the condition matches a HTTP header with a underscore in it?

example:

```
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_API_KEY}" pattern="flex-api!key" />
</conditions>
```

this matches a request with a HTTP header: `api-key: flex-api!key`

How can I define a condition that matches: `api_key: flex-api!key`

Comment: You should follow the conventions to only use `-` in your custom header.

Comment: You are completely right my sir! Unfortunately, my supplier is not following the conventions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access raw headers by prefixing `HEADER_` to the header name... `{HEADER_API_KEY}`

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspx - see section "HEADER_<HeaderName>".